# Symmetric Group $S_n$ is complete

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am just checking some properties of the symmetric group and found on Wikipedia the statement that "Conversely, for $n \neq 6$, $S_n$ has no outer automorphisms, and for $n \neq 2$ it has no center, so for $n \neq 2, 6$ it is a complete group, as discussed in automorphism group, below."

I could show that $Z(S_n)=1$ but do you know an easy proof for $\mathrm{Aut}(S_n)=\mathrm{Inn}(S_n)$ ?

Comment: Coincidentally I looked up this proof in Hupperts book about finite groups (I) this week since I also stumbled over this fact. The proof in Hupperts book is in my opinion rather technical (which is also the reason that I cannot recall it).

Comment: It is proved in Dummit and Foote's "Abstract Algebra" page 138 exercise 18.

Comment: Thank you ougao for the information. I was able to show part c and d, but could you tell me how a and b works?

Comment: For part a, it is clear when you notice that if a conjugacy class $\mathcal{K}$ is generated by $\tau$, then $\sigma{\mathcal{K}}$ is generated by $\sigma(\tau)$. For part b, note that any element of order 2 in $S_n$ is a product of two cycles (i.e., transpositions) and one cycles, so the conjugacy class it generated must have smaller size. and note that $\tau(i_1, \cdots, i_k)\tau^{-1}=(\tau(i_1), \cdots, \tau(i_k)).$

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Lemma**. Let $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ be the automorphism group of a group $G$ and $\mathrm{cl}(G)$ the conjugacy classes of elements of $G$. Then $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ acts on $\mathrm{cl}(G)$.

*Explanation*. Let $\alpha$ be an automorphism of $G$ and $\mathrm{cl}(a)=\{gag^{-1}:g\in G\}$ the conjugacy class of $a$. Then $\alpha(\mathrm{cl}(a))=\{\alpha(g)\alpha(a)\alpha(g)^{-1}:g\in G\}=\{t\alpha(a)t^{-1}:t\in G\}=\mathrm{cl}(\alpha(a))$ is also a class.

**Lemma**. If $\alpha\in\mathrm{Aut}(S_n)$ stabilizes the conjugacy class of transpositions then $\alpha\in\mathrm{Inn}(S_n)$ is inner.

*Proof*. We want to exhibit an element $\sigma\in S_n$ such that $\alpha(g)=\sigma g\sigma^{-1}$ for every $g$. It suffices to find a $\sigma$ for which $\alpha(\tau)=\sigma \tau\sigma^{-1}$ holds for every transposition $\tau$, since every permutation is a product of transpositions. It further suffices to find a $\sigma$ for which $\alpha(1k)=\sigma(1k)\sigma^{-1}$ for each $1< k\le n$, since these $n-1$ transpositions generate all the others.

Pick distinct $1<\ell_1,\ell_2\le n$. Then $\rho=(1\ell_2\ell_1)=(1\ell_1)(1\ell_2)$ has order $3$, in which case $\alpha(1\ell_1)\alpha(1\ell_2)$ has order three as well. Without loss of generality, $\alpha(1\ell_1)=(ab)$ and $\alpha(1\ell_2)=(ac)$ for some $a,b,c$; since this holds for each distinct pair $\ell_1,\ell_2$, we find that for every $k$, $\alpha(1k)=(af(k))$ for some $f(k)$.

Let $\sigma$ send $1$ to $a$ and $k$ to $f(k)$ for each $k>1$. This permutation satisfies our requirements.

**Lemma**. For $n\ne6$, the class of transpositions is the unique class of involutions with ${n\choose2}$ elements.

*Proof*. Consider the class of involutions with cycle type a product of $k>1$ disjoint cycles. Suppose

$$\frac{1}{k!}{n\choose 2}{n-2\choose2}\cdots{n-2(k-1)\choose2}={n\choose2}.$$

The LHS is the size of the new conjugacy class. Setting $m=n-2$ and $k=r+1$, cancelling ${n\choose2}$s,

$${m\choose2}\cdots{m-2(r-1)\choose2}=(r+1)!$$

The LHS is telescoping. Multiply by $2^r/(2r)!$ and get

$${m\choose2r}=\frac{(r+1)!2^r}{(2r)!}=\frac{r+1}{(2r-1)!!}$$

For $r>2$ the RHS is not even an integer (it is $<1$). The case $r=1$ gives $m(m-1)=4$ with no solution in $m$. Finally $r=2$ gives $m(m-1)(m-2)(m-3)=24$ which has positive solution $4$.

**Theorem**. For $n\ne6$, $\mathrm{Out}(S_n)=1$.

*Proof*. Combine the three lemmas. When $n\ne6$, automorphisms permute conjugacy classes and in particular stabilize the transposition class (since the size of this class is unique among the classes), hence every automorphism is inner.

**Remark**. This proof is adapted from [this sketch from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphisms_of_the_symmetric_and_alternating_groups#No_other_outer_automorphisms) and [these notes](http://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~eal/S6.pdf).

Comment: Presumably I am downvoted for adapting a proof from other places? Or perhaps is it for having a proof that is not easy, as desired?

Comment: This is quite elegant. By far, my favorite proof of this fact I've seen yet.

Comment: This proof is surprising!