# Why every automorphism of $S_3$ is inner Automorphism But This is not case with $S_6$?

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, automorphism-group

I can show Inner Automorphism of $S_3$ are isomorphic to $S_3$ .Why every automorphism of $S_3$ is inner automorphism only? That is why there is no automorphism of $S_3$ exist that is not inner automorphism .
Why this is not in case of $S_6$? 
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I know that but why all automorphism of $S_3$ are inner only That was my question.Can you help me please?

Comment: Any automorphism of $S_3$ must permute its three elements of order $2$. Since they generate $S_3$ this means that there are at most $6$ automorphisms. But there are $6$ inner automorphisms.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258824/) for the case $n \ne 6$.

Answer (score 1):

In $S_3$, every automorphism must fix all the conjugacy classes, because distinct conjugacy classes correspond to distinct elements' orders (automorphisms preserve elements' order). So, each automorphism is class-preserving, hence cycle type-preserving. In particular, it sends transpositions to transpositions, and [hence](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Transposition-preserving_automorphism_of_symmetric_group_is_inner) it is inner.

In $S_4$ and $S_5$, the classes of the transpositions and the double transpositions have different sizes. So, again, every automorphism is transpositions-preserving (automorphisms preserve classes' size), hence it is inner.

On the other hand, $S_6$ fulfils the necessary conditions for a non-inner automorphism to exist, namely the existence of conjugacy classes of elements of order $2$, which have also the same size: the classes of transpositions and triple transpositions both have size $15$. This doesn't prove yet that such non-inner automorphisms exist (swapping the two classes), but at least makes plausible their existence, here.

Comment: I've edited, @ArturoMagidin.

Comment: Now the claim is that "cycle type preserving" (which for $S_n$ is just another way of saying conjugacy class preserving) is equivalent to inner, but again, that's not necessarily obvious. In $A_3$ all automorphisms are cycle-type preserving, but not all of them are inner. As I recall, proving this takes a bit more work: you usually prove that an automorphism that sends transpositions to transpositions must be inner (and it is not obvious).

Comment: You can take care of $n\lt 6$ and $n\gt 6$ together using that fact: transpositions must be sent to a product of an odd number of disjoint transpositions (for order-preservation, and so that not every element gets mapped to an even permutation). For $n\lt 6$, this forces transpositions to be mapped to transpositions. For $n\geq 6$, class preservation means the set of all transpositions would have to be mapped to the set of all products of $2k+1$ transpositions for a fixed $k$, and size considerations means that the only non-inner possibility is $k=1$, $n=6$.